# Tensorflow failing to restore .index file

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence

I am currently attempting to import a tensorflow model. I have all the files needed for import in a directory, x.meta, x.index, x.chkp.data-00000-of-00001, and the checkpoint file.

I first run

```
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(meta_name)
```

which runs completely fine.
Then I attempt to import the .index file into a regular session

```
saver.restore(sess,dir+index_name)
```

and the code fails.

I get this error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Tensor name "z/w" not found in checkpoint files ./x.index
```

The strange thing is that depending on when I run it, I get different errors! Sequential runs will return different tensors that fail to be found, no matter if I close my shell or not.

I've tried restarting my machine, I retrained my network and used fresh files, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: First thing I notice: I usually just do `saver.restore(sess, dir + name_root)` where `name_root` does not include the extension `.index` or whatever. Doubt that's the problem, but thought I'd mention it.

Comment: Same here. I usually get just give the `name.ckpt` without the trailing extensions; the saver would then read all 3 files : index, meta, and data-00000-of-00001

Comment: Have you tried ```saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint(dir))```?